# Advanced Fitness Program

Tags: bodybuilding

Can anyone recommend somewhere where I can get or buy fitness programs for body building?

I want to change my program every 6 weeks or so.

I was using a personal trainer but he has moved to a different gym.

Can anyone re

Comment: Mind completeing your question?

Comment: What's your motivation for changing the program every 6 weeks?

Comment: @dagda1 What exactly are you goals and what do you want to achieve in the end? Asking for an "advanced fitness program" is rather vague and open to interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I can reccommend from experience is [bodybuilding.com](http://www.bodybuilding.com/guides/). Did the Gething 12 week transformation myself, dropped about 50 pounds in 12 weeks.